# sum in JSON response and display in html angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a response json like this

```
[{id:'1' ,name :'A',amout:'50'},
{id:'2',name:'B',amount:'60'},
{id:'3',name:'C',amount:'40'}]
```

I want sum amout . I want `result = 150` and display in html.

How can i do that

Comment: why dont you use a simple angular foreach and sum up them

Comment: okay keep coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
 app.filter('totalFilter', function() {
return function(data, key) {
  if (angular.isUndefined(data) || angular.isUndefined(key)){
    return 0;}
  var sum = 0;
  angular.forEach(data, function(v, k) {
    sum = sum + parseInt(v[key]);
  });
  return sum;
}
```

});

Use the $filter service:

In controller..

```
         var Total= $filter('totalFilter')($scope.datas, 'amount');
          console.log(Total);
```

Or.      You can use in html

```
        <tr ng-repeat="data in datas">                                         
        <td>{{data.amount}}    </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
         Total amount : {{ datas | totalFilter:'amount' }}
        </tr>
```